# How to use a custom FormType in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I m training but I'm under symfony 3

i have problem i get this error

> Expected argument of type "string",
>   "Test\FrontBundle\Form\Type\SheetType" given

the code on SheetType.php is

```
<?php

namespace Test\FrontBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class SheetType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',null,array('label'=>'Titre de l\'album'))
            ->add('type')
            ->add('artist')
            ->add('duration')
            ->add('released', DateType::class)
            ;
    }
}
```

and on my SheetController.php i do that form my controller
i dont know how i can solve this all time i try else i got error

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new SheetType());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->isMethod('post') && $form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('test_front_sheet_list'));
        } 
        return $this->render('TestFrontBundle:Sheet:create.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Since symfony 2.8 you have to pass a full qualified class name instance as argument when create a form or form builder, it does not take an instance of `FormTypeInterface` anymore.

see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md

So you should use `$form = $this->createForm(SheetType::class);` instead.

Comment: How can we now pass custom attribute in formType ? I used to do that : `new MyFormType($customAttr)` but now as we have to pass the fully qualified class name of the form type I can't do this anymore..